# image not upload on server with file-transfer plugin ionic3

Tags: ionic3, image-uploading, file-transfer

can't upload a file in database

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
let imgData: FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: 'image',
  fileName: n.toString() + ".png",
  headers: {}
}
console.log(imgData);
fileTransfer.upload(img, 'API', imgData)
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
    alert("success");
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    alert("error");
  });
```

Cleartext HTTP traffic to not permitted